# Remove all lines from a given text file based on a given list of IDs

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a list of IDs like so:

```
11002
10995
48981
```

And a tab delimited file like so:

```
11002   Bacteria;
10995   Metazoa
```

I am trying to delete all lines in the tab delimited file containing one of the IDs from the ID list file. For some reason the following won't work and just returns the same complete tab delimited file without any line removed whatsoever:

```
 grep -v -f ID_file.txt tabdelimited_file.txt > New_tabdelimited_file.txt
```

I also tried numerous other combinations with grep, but currently I draw blank here.

Any idea why this is failing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged this with `awk`, here is one way of doing it:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}NR==FNR{ids[$1]++;next}!($1 in ids)' idFile tabFile > new_tabFile
```

BTW your `grep` command is correct. Just double check if your file is not formatted for windows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this also doesn't seem to work, same result (nothing gets removed from the tab delimited text file). Not sure how I can check if my files are correctly formatted though..

Comment: @user2600287 Do `cat -vet` on your file. If you see `^M` at the end then you need to convert it back to unix format. You can use `dos2unix` for that.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Making a new text file in Linux rather than using the one transferred from Windows also solved the problem, so you were right

Comment: You could have fixed the files with `dos2unix` or `sed -i 's/\r$//'` or `tr -d '\r'`

Comment: I like your awk solution, worked on a very large file whereas the grep -v solution did not.